# How to assign an existing connection ID to a new signal R connection by javascript?

Tags: javascript, signalr

For example, I start in a browser tab, but I would like to use the same connection when opening new tabs or when opening a new browser window. I thought about using the same connection id, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen anything in the documentation that suggest you can do that. Each connection is opened and the client is connected with a new ID.

What you probably want to do is when your client connects is add them to their own group. They can then receive data through that group no matter how many tabs, browsers or devices they connect with.

Depending on which you are using refer to these sections of the docs -

ASP.NET 4.x - [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups)
ASP.NET CORE - [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: If each client opens a connection it will become unfeasible, since I use IIS and it is limited to 10 connections. That's why I would like it to be a single connection, so as not to suffer from this limitation.

Comment: Limited to 10 connections? If you are referring to this, it only applies if you are not running from a "server" but rather a desktop. I think the default is 4,000 connections under IIS 8. Ref - "if a client operating system is used, such as for development (Windows 8 or Windows 7), full versions of IIS or Cassini should not be used, since there will be a limit of 10 simultaneous connections imposed" from - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms